# Managing hdfs in pseudo-distributed hadoop mode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to do some computation with hadoop and mahout on my quad core machine, so I am using hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode.

The problem is that the space on my root drve is limited, so how can I configure it to use space available on some other external hard drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure where hdfs strores its data. Add the following to your conf/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>__path_to_where_you_want_to_store_your_data/hdfs/data/</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>__path_to_where_you_want_to_store_your_data/hdfs/name/</value>
</property>
```

After theese changes you will have to format your namenode:

`hadoop namenode -format`

Comment: but the hadoop doesn't start after that. It keeps showing that the namenode is in safe mode

Comment: maybe you also have to configure the dfs.name dir:                        <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/Users/helmut/programmieren/hdfs/name/</value>
</property>
                                                                  dfs.data.dir and dfs.name.dir should point to a location on your external drive. After changing theese values reformat your hdfs filesystem with `hadoop namenode -format`

Comment: After doing a `hadoop namenode -format`, it's necessary to delete anything in the dfs.name.dir